# Is it possible to use composite templates with Bulk send in Docusign?

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusign-sdk

I am working on a project that requires sending thousands of envelopes to individuals within a relatively short time window. To avoid hitting the DocuSign API rules and limits, I am considering using the Bulk Send feature. This way, I can batch thousands of recipients and send them an envelope with fewer requests.

These thousands of people will not receive the exact same envelopes but will have different tab data. The scenario we are trying to build is as follows:

There are several templates in DocuSign, such as Template A, Template B, and Template C.

Each recipient will receive a specific subset of Template A, Template B, and Template C. For example, if there are 10,000 recipients:

- 5,000 recipients will receive a combination of Template A and Template B in their envelope and sign it in one go.
- 3,000 recipients will receive a combination of Template B and Template C in their envelope and sign it in one go.
- 1,000 recipients will receive a combination of Template A and Template C in their envelope and sign it in one go.
- 100 recipients will receive a combination of Template A, Template B, and Template C in their envelope and sign it in one go.
- 500 recipients will receive only Template A and sign it in one go.
- 300 recipients will receive only Template B and sign it in one go.
- 100 recipients will receive only Template C and sign it in one go.

Please note that each template has some fields that should have a different value for each recipient, such as Title, Salary, etc.

I am aware of the Composite Template feature in DocuSign, which helps merge multiple server templates into the same envelope when sending to a recipient. However, I'm not entirely sure how this works with the Bulk Send API.

Is there a way to achieve this? If so, I am using the C# SDK. Is it possible with the SDK, or do I need to use the REST API for this?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you create the draft envelope for use with bulk sending, create it with composite templates.

Then send it via bulk envelopes. This [page](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/bulk-send-envelopes/) gives some info.

Also, you can talk with your DocuSign contacts to have your API limits increased during your project.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and report back.